# Localization in .netcore 2.1 MVC application using CookieRequestCultureProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating .netcore 2.1 MVC application.

We have to support multiple languages for UI and messages returned by controller.

I followed the link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1

On any browser say Chrome, in 2 tabs I logged in with user A and User B. If user A change his prefer language his/ her UI reflects UI in correct language. All good.
Now if I refresh User B tab and refresh UI language gets changed for him/ her also.

I am using below code:

```
public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
        Response.Cookies.Append(
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
            CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
            new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1),IsEssential=true }
        );

        return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
}
```

I thought I should create separate cookie for each user say by appending userid in cookie name. But this does not work.

What more core changes I need to do may be startup.cs or somewhere else so applications knows that name of new cookie is not default and thread read the right cookie and load culture info onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if I refresh User B tab and refresh UI language gets changed for him/ her also

This is expected behavior because browser doesn't create cookie for user logged in to site but it creates cookie in a browser for certain domain (site url). So whether user `A` or user `B` change language the cookie will be set in browser for all users.

> I thought I should create separate cookie for each user say by appending userid in cookie name

You cannot accomplish this because you can specify only 1 custom culture cookie name for `CookieRequestCultureProvider` and it's not possible to support multiple cookie names based on user Id.